# How to i save a new entry in array to local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an comoponent where i add a new playlist, I've made a function to add a playlist to the playlist array, but when i refresh the page, de new entry is gone. i have tried to save to localStroge, but it doesn't seem te work? how do i fix this? I also have a db.json file where i fetch the playlist data, can i possibly save there if localStorage wont work?

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  CircularProgress,
  Stack,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import MIcons from "../Utils/MIcons";
import PlayLists, { PlayListValues } from "./PlayLists";

const Home = () => {
  const [playLists, setPlayLists] = useState<PlayListValues[]>([]);
  const [newList, setNewList] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/playList`).then((res) => {
        const response = res.data;
        setPlayLists(response);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.debug(err, "error");
    }
  }, []);

  const addPlayList = () => {
    if (newList) {
      let num = playLists?.length + 1;
      let newEntry = { id: num, title: newList, songs: [] };
      setPlayLists([...playLists, newEntry]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("playLists", JSON.stringify(playLists));
  }, [playLists]);

  console.log(playLists, "playlist");

  return (
    <Box>
      <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} justifyContent="space-between" m={2}>
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
          <MIcons.LibraryMusic />
          <Typography variant="subtitle1">Your playlists</Typography>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
      <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} m={2} justifyContent="center">
        {playLists && <PlayLists playList={playLists} />}
        {!playLists && <CircularProgress />}
      </Stack>
      <TextField
        label="Add playList"
        variant="outlined"
        value={newList}
        onChange={(e) => setNewList(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Button onClick={addPlayList}>add</Button>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Can you dump the value of `playLists` variable here as an example

Comment: ```  "playList": [
  {
  "id":1,
  "title":"My playList 1",
   "songs":[
    {
     "id": 190,
     "name": "(Don't Fear) The Reaper",
     "year": 1975,
     "artist": "Blue Öyster Cult",
     "shortname": "dontfearthereaper",
     "bpm": 141,
     "duration": 322822,
     "genre": "Classic Rock",
     "spotifyId": "5QTxFnGygVM4jFQiBovmRo",
     "album": "Agents of Fortune"
    }
   ]```

Comment: Cool, so you have set the localStorage, but you are not retrieving it anywhere. How do expect the code to check localstorage? You need to have `localStorage.getItem` in your logic to meet your fallback code expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the initial value from localStorage

```
const [playLists, setPlayLists] = useState<PlayListValues[]>(localStorage.getItem('playLists') || []);
```

Answer (score -1):

You wrote an useEffect that render every change on your playList state, So when you refresh your browser the component render again and the playlist state got its initial value that is [] empty array the your useEffect called and set empty array in localStorage! So you should wrap your localStorage.setItem in a condition like below:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if(!!playLists.length){
localStorage.setItem("playLists", JSON.stringify(playLists));
}
  }, [playLists]);
```

Comment: doesn't solve the problem